# Mocking methods to throw Error phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

PHPUnit let me make a method stub to throw an Exception, using either of:

- `[->will($this->throwException(..)][1]`
- `->willThrowException(..`

I need to test some cases where the method stub throws PHP Errors.

Does PHPUnit support anything like this? Any workarounds here?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You can *throw* exceptions, and you can *trigger* errors.

Comment: My semantics may be off. But, I wanted to make by stub throw/trigger errors. Answered it myself.

Comment: Note that this works in PHP 7 and upwards only, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The throwException() in PHPUnit TestCase class can take any instance of Throwable as param.

This means,

```
->will($this->throwException(new Error()));
->will($this->throwException(new Exception()));
```

are both valid

Comment: By the way, you can use `willThrowException()` instead.

Comment: Nope, willThrowException() can only take in type of Exception as the param, not an Error.

Comment: Just for information, the `willThrowException()` method now accepts `\Throwable` not just `\Exception` on PHPUnit 8 (8.2 at least, didn't tried on earlier version)

Comment: @NikhilKuriakose: If this answers the question, please mark it as "answer".

Answer (score 18):

You can make a function in a test throw an exception like so:

```
$handlerConsentMessage = $this->getMockBuilder('YourClass')
            ->setMethods(array('yourMethod'))->getMock();

$handlerConsentMessage->method('yourMethod')->willThrowException(new Exception());

$handlerConsentMessage->run('functionToRun');
```

Now when you run your test function functionToRun if the function YourMethod is ever called it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Just trigger an error:

```
$foo
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('bar')
    ->willReturnCallback(function () {
        trigger_error(
            'Now really is not a good time',
            E_USER_ERROR
        );
    });
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php

Comment: Nice, now it get's interesting. I assume both the behaviours(your answer and mine) will give the exact same output?

Comment: Ha, yours is definitely better and makes more sense on PHP7. Haven't had the need yet to mock triggering an error (as opposed to throwing exceptions), so I haven't really used what I suggested here before.

Comment: But, this is good. I was searching for answers for hours, and suddenly I have two :) Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad you like it! Often makes sense to ask someone, hehe!

Answer (score -5):

High quality code does not produce any PHP errors (notice, warning, fatal, parse errors) during normal work. If it still produces errors - you should **try to detect such edge cases and throw exceptions / return different result**. Then these exceptions are easily mockable in PHPUnit tests.

**Other workaround, if not possible to modify tested class**, - is to define error listener inside your test, see [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). The logic should be following:

1. Tested method generates some error, for example a warning
2. The warning is catch by set_error_handler inside of your test.
3. Inside set_error_handler's callback you set some variable, to indicate that warning was catch. (it could be some static property, or another storage)
4. In the end of test you assert that static property has certain value = it means that warning was generated.

Comment: Thanks, but i am working on a library which can have unhandled exceptions/thrown errors from the client.

Comment: OK, then to handle any kind of errors you may use @expectedException PHPUnit\Framework\Error annotation (https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.errors) or if you are interested in detecting which exactly error was generated - set_error_handler always helps